# MongoDB C# Drive doesn't allow '.' in documents field names

Tags: c#, mongodb

Currently I want to have keys with dots in my documents, but unfortunately the current MongoDB driver 2.4.3 doesn't allow it.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
   Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   dic.Add(@"magic.key", "test.test");

   var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);

   var docToInsert = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(data);

   MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

   IMongoDatabase DB = client.GetDatabase("testDB");

   IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> col = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testCol");

   col.InsertOne(docToInsert);
```

This is the exception thrown:

```
   Element name 'magic.key' is not valid'.
```

Again, I am using MongoDB.Driver from MongoDB, Inc, downloaded from NuGet, the version I am using is 2.4.3

I tried using a escape character but it didn't work, other SO posts said that it is not possible, but some time passed and I would like to know if there is a solution now.

I tried and verified that older versions of MongoDB (1.0 and 1.1) do allow it, is there any way to achieve this with the current driver? or I will have to stick with the old one?

Comment: Which driver are you using. There are a lot of diffrent once for C#. Give us a code you are using as well. Please redo your question with more data, since we have no idea what is your context, errors and what you have tried.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak Sorry, I though it was clear. When I read it again I understood how confusing it was, I updated the post with the code and the exact exception.